# Custom dimension in collective.googleanalytics report

Tags: python, google-analytics, plone, google-analytics-api, plone-4.x

I'm using collective.googleanalytics (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.googleanalytics) to add some GA reports to a plone site.

How can I use custom dimensions (like ga:dimension1 or ga:dimension2) in a new google analytics report? I can't see any related option in Query Dimensions field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved updating collective.googleanalytics config.py to support custom dimensions.

```
DIMENSIONS_CHOICES = (
    ...
    "ga:dimension1",
    "ga:dimension2",
    "ga:dimension3",
    "ga:dimension4",
    "ga:dimension5",
```